# Heaviside produces different outcomes in Matlab

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I'm really puzzled with the following:

```
>> syms z p
>> heaviside(z)
ans =
heaviside(z)
>> heaviside(p)
ans =
1
```

If you use almost any other variable instead of 'z' it still works perfectly, but with 'p' (and also with 'p1', 'p2' etc) it's suddenly 1. No prior assumptions on symbolic variables. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Edit:
That was indeed something with the workspace. I got how to fix it but still can’t understand:

```
>> syms p positive
>> heaviside(p)
ans =
1
>> clear
>> syms p
>> heaviside(p)
ans =
1
>> clear
>> syms p clear
>> heaviside(p)
ans =
heaviside(p)
```

So why just 'clear' the workspace is not enough?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behavior. Which Matlab version are you using? I tried your example with MATLAB Version 7.10.0.499 (R2010a) (with Symbolic Math Toolbox Version 5.4) and got `heaviside(z)` and `heaviside(p)` as answers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm using Matlab Version 8.1.0.604 (R2013a) with Symbolic Math Toolbox Version 5.10

Comment: I cannot reproduce this in MATLAB 7.12.0 (R2011a). I get the same results as @Schorsch.

Comment: I can't reproduce this either.  I am using MATLAB R2014a.  I get `heaviside(z)` and `heaviside(p)` as verified by Schorsch and Robert P.

Comment: @Evgeny : Try clearing your workspace and do this again.  There could be some previously declared variables that could be making MATLAB do this unexpected behaviour

Comment: @Evgeny: I still can't reproduce the error that you have.  Clearing your variables then invoking `syms p, heaviside(p);` produces what I expect.  I'm using MATLAB 8.3.0.532 (R2014a) with the Symbolic Math Toolbox version 6.0

Comment: The answer is here http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/symbolic/clear-assumptions-and-reset-the-symbolic-engine.html: If you make an assumption about the nature of a variable, for example, using the commands ... then clearing the variable x from the MATLAB workspace does not clear the assumption from the symbolic engine workspace. Anyway, `syms p clear` solves the problem.